# I want to learn Blender

Tags: modeling

I've been learning Blender for 2 years. Due to my job, I couldn't do it systematically. Now I have more time and I would like to develop my skills. In the future, I would like to make models for games.

Here is the link to my portfolio:
https://www.artstation.com/watus1992r
Can you write what next model should I make to develop my skills?
I want to make more and more difficult models.

Comment: This forum is for answers to problems with using Blender, not what you should do with it, so your question will problably be closed as unsuitable here. Suggest you try somewhere like https://blenderartists.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Im in the same boat as you and what im doing is recreating scenes from around me such as my street or room. I find it to be a good balance between following tutorials and actually modelling